# Early morning study

Tags: single-word-requests

*Lucubration* is the act of intensely studying late into the night (historically, by candlelight). What would a similar word be for studying early in the morning?

E.g.
I woke up before the sun rose for some quality [word]. After all, the early bird gets the worm.

Comment: I don’t have enough Latin to do a morphemic analysis of *lucubration*. But as you said, and etymonline confirms [1], *lucubration* is to work by artificial light. Now it’s arguable that this also applies to the dark of the pre-dawn, but I’m more interested in extracting the *work by* morpheme from *lucubration*, so we can rip off \*leuk and replace it with another stem specifically meaning *morning light*. Which stem is that? Why, ***lucifer***, of course [2]. Or any other name for Venus, like Greek *Hesperus* (himself industrious). But I’ve already developed a fondness for *lucifercubration*.

Comment: [1] https://www.etymonline.com/word/lucubration#etymonline_v_14584 and [2] https://www.etymonline.com/word/Lucifer#etymonline_v_14578

Comment: I am rather hoping that some clever person will come up with something to do with birdsong, or 'dawn chorus'. _Auroracation_ from the Latin word _aurora_ 'dawn'.

Comment: _Lucubration_ is from Latin _lūcubrāt-, < lūc-, lūx_ light. I'm not sure what "ubrāt" means there. It is something to do with night so it might be related to "umbra". _Mane_ is morning in Latin so I could coin _lucmanation_ or _lumanation_ perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *lucubration* is already an uncommon word, why not try **matins**. They originally referred to a morning church service, but in literary use they have been generalized to refer to an early morning task or occupation. Here's the quotes for the Oxford English Dictionary entry:

> 1641   Milton Reason Church-govt. 36   These and such like lessons as these, I know would have been my **Matins** duly, and my Even-song.
>
> 1814   Wordsworth Excursion ii. 58   The music and the sprightly scene Invite us; shall we quit our road, and join These festive **matins** ?

Comment: I like your answer, and the examples are great! I especially enjoy the subtle nod to birdsong that it implies. My only gripe is that there doesn't seem to be a widely used verb form (widely being relative here). Still, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Lucubration is derived by the Latin lemma
"lucubrare, lucubrat-", which means "to work at night by lamplight", as "luc" (from lux) denotes the "light".

I think "enlightenment" and "meditation" could be related to the meaning of a  "laborious, intense and pendantic study" and make sort of a match or a synonym.